# grab only part of a grok match in logstash

Tags: logstash, grok

I imagine there has to be a way to do this but I can't figure out the way to do it from the documentation I could find

I have a patterns file to identify the types of the request:

```
FOO .*foo.* #request type foo 
BAR .*bar.* #request type bar
```

I want to grab the type of the request from something that looks like
http://something.com/foo/aaa

My logstash filters contains something like the following:

```
match => { "request" => [ "%{FOO:req_type}", "%{BAR:req_type}" ] }
```

I would like the word "foo" to be assigned to "req_type" instead I get the whole request. I am not sure how to just get the part I need

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define custom grok patterns for this, but you can leverage the existing `URI` pattern and then split the extracted `URIPATH` on `/` and assign the first path component to `req_type`. It goes like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{URI}" } 
    named_captures_only => false
  }
  mutate {
     split => { "URIPATH" => "/" }
     add_field => {"req_type" => "%{URIPATH[1]}" }
  }
}
```

Your event will then be similar to this (note the `req_type` field at the bottom):

```
{
         "message" => "http://something.com/foo/aaa",
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2016-06-03T04:45:25.731Z",
            "host" => "iMac.local",
             "URI" => "http://something.com/foo/aaa",
        "URIPROTO" => "http",
         "URIHOST" => "something.com",
        "IPORHOST" => "something.com",
        "HOSTNAME" => "something.com",
    "URIPATHPARAM" => "/foo/aaa",
         "URIPATH" => [
        [0] "",
        [1] "foo",
        [2] "aaa"
    ],
        "req_type" => "foo"
}
```

Note that you can use `remove_field` to remove anything that is not necessary to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this doesn't solve the issue I am dealing with since the req_type will be different parts of the url and sometimes a combinations of sections e.g `URIPATH[1]` sometimes and `URIPATH[3]` sometimes and sometimes a combination of two `URIPATH[1] + URIPATH[2]`

Comment: Can you provide more URL samples that you need to grok?